# Rails delete goes to show action when alert canceled

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a simple model destroy button in view which is caught by rails so that confirmation box is shown. When i press OK, it properly destroys the item, but when i press Cancel it goes to Show action instead of...well, just nothing.

I have tried 4.2 bundled jquery, 1.11.1 and latest.
Also bundled jquery-ui and latest.

jquery_ujs is included, otherwise delete wouldn't work.

What could be a problem here?

**UPDATE**

```
<%= link_to student_path(student),
    method: :delete,
    data: { confirm: t('.confirm', default: t("helpers.links.confirm", default: 'Ste prepričani?')) },
    class: 'btn btn-xs btn-danger' do -%>
  <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for your cancel button? And any JS code that might be attached to it?

Comment: I've updated my question. There is nothing extra attached to that link.

Comment: This looks like code for the delete button, not the cancel button.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. The problem is when i click on this button and confirmation popup is presented > and when i click cancel: instead of just close the popup it goes to show action.

Comment: Where is the cancel link/button?

Comment: @MitjaČebokli I'm not sure what's going on, but your data-confirm looks different than I've seen it. Do things work properly if you change it to `data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }`

Comment: By "Show action instead of...well, just nothing." you mean what is the url? The code posted looks totally ok to me but your explanation is a little confusing

Comment: Normally, when one presses cancel/no in alert box it just closes the alert, without any action, the page should just stay wherever it was, not going to show action.

Comment: What do you mean? It is a standard rails_ujs data-confirm dialog with OK and Cancel buttons.